# jquery indexOf replacement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have a hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" value="php,php mysql" id="tags"/>
```

and I also have a normal input box which users could add their new tags, now I want to check if the new tag which user wants to add is already added for him or not, if it's already added, alert('already there');

here is my code:

```
var already_added = $('#tags_final').val().toLowerCase();
new_tag = new_tag.toLowerCase();
if (already_added.indexOf(new_tag) < 0){
// add it, everything is OK
}else{
alert('already there');
}
```

the above works just fine for normal values, for example now if i try to add "php", this is gonna alert('already there'), the problem is, if I add "mysql", this also sends the alert since it finds it in "php mysql", but "mysql" is another tag and it needs to be added. what's solutions come to mind for this?

thanks for your help

Comment: you could split the whole value string into an array (split using the "," vlaue), then check each element of the array for your exact tag

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices `indexOf()` also works with arrays.

Comment: @JosephSilber IE gets [polyfill](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think you'd want to break this up into separate pieces and perform a full text comparison on the actual tag itself.

```
var tags = $('#tags_final').val().toLowerCase().split(',');
new_tag = new_tag.toLowerCase();

if ($.inArray(new_tag, tags) < 0) {
    // add it
} else {
    alert('already there');
}
```

```
var tags = $('#tags_final').val().toLowerCase().split(',');
new_tag = new_tag.toLowerCase();

if (tags.indexOf(new_tag) < 0) {
    // add it
} else {
    alert('already there');
}
```

*Edit: Courtesy of @nybbler, this would be more accurate using the jquery inArray method as linked in his comment.*

Comment: Since jQuery is in use here, you should use jQuery's inArray (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) instead of Array.indexOf as it is not available in IE < 9

Comment: @nybbler: Thanks for that. I haven't run across that method before (I don't traverse arrays this way often). I'll post an update reflecting that piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `indexOf` directly on the string is faster than either a regex or splitting into an array (even more so when relying on [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)).

Simply wrap your `already_added` string of tags with commas, then do the same for the tag when searching for it with `indexOf`:

```
var already_added = ',' + $('#tags_final').val().toLowerCase() + ',';
new_tag = new_tag.toLowerCase();

if (already_added.indexOf(',' + new_tag + ',') < 0) {
    // add it
} else {
    alert('already there');
}
```

I got this idea from [a similar trick used by jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L88).

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed - I'm not following your logic; look at very first line of code in my answer.

Comment: @JosephSilber The performance gains you might get out of using string.indexOf will be negated by the string concatenation required.  See this jsPerf test (http://jsperf.com/strings-v-arrays) that shows Array.indexOf or jQuerys $.inArray as the fastest and this solution as the slowest (tested in Chrome22, IE9, and FF11)

Comment: @nybbler - I stand corrected, though I still don't understand how a simple concatenation can be more expensive than a `split`.

Answer (score 0):

Save the tags between braces [php][php mysql]
and search for it

```
var already_added = $('#tags_final').val().toLowerCase();
new_tag = new_tag.toLowerCase();
if (already_added.indexOf("["+new_tag+"]") < 0){
// add it, everything is OK
}else{
alert('already there');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this to look for a key in a comma separated string of keys:

```
function contains(keys, key) {
  var i = 0, k = key.length;
  for (var i = 0;(i = keys.indexOf(key, i)) != -1; i += k) {
    if ((i == 0 || keys.charAt(i - 1) == ',') && (i + k == keys.length || keys.charAt(i + k) == ',')) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/UHH9V/